# PYTHON 3 (1) Dictionary Python upper case values present in a single key. (2) Why datatype sets in python does not return True element?

Tags: python, python-3.x

(1) A snippet that takes a dictionary and uppercases every value in the dictionary and sets that value back into the dictionary at the same key e.g.

Given:

```
d = {'a': ['amber', 'ash'], 'b': ['bart', 'betty']}
```

Result:

```
{'a': ['AMBER', 'ASH'], 'b': ['BART', 'BETTY']}
```

(2) Why datatype `SET` does not return `TRUE` element when printed?
Eg.
`{'hi', 1, True}` returns only `{'hi', 1}`

For (1) I am using something like this:

```
 d = {'a': ['amber', 'ash'], 'b': ['bart', 'betty']} 
 d.update((k, v.upper()) for k, v in d.items())
```

Comment: For (1) I am using something like this, d = {'a': ['amber', 'ash'], 'b': ['bart', 'betty']}
d.update((k, v.upper()) for k,v in d.items())

Comment: `set` containing `1` and `True` ? because `1==True`

Comment: This is not a homework-doing service.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, I'm new to python basics, i tried doing it successfully for one value but what is to be done for two or more values linked to a single key

Comment: @VaibhavSinha next time don't comment with your attempt, [edit] your question instead (at first I didn't see it and downvoted!)

Comment: also, it's better to ask 2 questions because both parts of your question are unrelated (and the second question is quite puzzling)

Answer (score 3):

(1)

```
d2 = {key:[name.upper() for name in names] for key, names in d.items()}
```

(2)

That seems to be because `True == 1` yields `True`, which is what the Set uses to check if the value added is already in the Set and therefore has to be ignored.

Comment: @Jean-François spoon-feeding askers of homework dumps is far from "nice". Please only encourage behaviour that's helpful for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndrasDeak it's not a homework dump. It's homework, but not dump. There _is_ an attempt (I even retracted my close vote). I admit that the question should be 2 questions, though. that's the one reproach we can do to that question.

Comment: @Jean-François you're right, I missed that. The question needs some work. Still, pure code lines as answers are suboptimal.

Comment: @AndrasDeak that's his first answer. Give the guy some slack (check 1 rep answers, almost all in the NAA queue). But you're right. For the explanations, see _my_ answer :)

Answer (score 1):

(1) Could be shorter, just in one line as shown by others answers, but here is trade off between complexity and "Pythonicity":

```
d = {'a': ['amber', 'ash'], 'b': ['bart', 'betty']}
for k in d:
    d[k] = [i.upper() for i in d[k]]

print(d)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'a': ['AMBER', 'ASH'], 'b': ['BART', 'BETTY']}
```

(2) Because `True == 1` is true and Python set objects just have items that are differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is:

```
d.update((k, v.upper()) for k,v in d.items())
```

That doesn't work that way. For instance, `v` is a `list`, you cannot `upper` a list...

This kind of transformation is better done using a dictionary comprehension to rebuild a new version of `d`. You can do the upper part for each value using list comprehension:

```
d = {k:[v.upper() for v in vl] for k,vl in d.items()}
```

For your second question: since `1==True`, the `set` keeps only the first inserted, which here is `1`. but could have been `True`: example:

```
>>> {True,1}
{1}
>>> {True,1,True}
{True}
>>> {1,True}
{True}
>>>
```

more deterministic: pass a `list` to build the `set` instead of using the `set` notation:

```
>>> set([True,1])
{True}
>>> set([1,True])
{1}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I get your point now My snippet fails because it is trying to change the case of the list which makes no sense. Thank you!

Comment: Jeronimo answer is better because it uses meaningful names. The values are names. Once you wrote that, you know that you have to iterate on them.

Comment: "the `set` keeps only the first inserted"- I'm not sure that's right?

Comment: @Chris_Rands for `set(['hi',1,True])` I'm sure of this. But ok, let me dig into this (maybe matter for another question ... or duplicate :)) what the hell, it doesn't work :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre But `{'hi',1,True}` is different (at least on my system on Py3)

Comment: @Chris_Rands >>> set(['hi',1,True])
{1, 'hi'}
>>> set(['hi',True,1])
{True, 'hi'}
>>> set(['hi',True,0])
{0, True, 'hi'}
>>>

Comment: @Chris_Rands I stand corrected on "first inserted". It's just that you cannot predict the first inserted :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Isn't it the "last inserted" that is kept for `set` literals? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @Chris_Rands you may be right, but it's probably implementation defined. tested on py2 & 3 and it seems to be the same. I

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I might be wrong, and i also don't know if it's guaranteed. anyway, sorry I'm drifting off-topic...

Comment: don't be. It's kind of interesting

Comment: @Chris_Rands https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004328/order-of-insertion-in-sets :) in case you're not checking the questions now

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah thanks, I'll follow the discussion with interest!